# Material MUI. Custom Variant that Honours Style and Palette Rules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

### Context

I'm trying to do a small POC for our company. We're trying to assess if we want to continue our relationship with MUI. Our design department has massive dreams about customising the UI of our apps substantially and diverging from MUI and building a new UI framework from the ground up to compete with MUI.

I'm of the opinion this could be done via a theme on MUI, with just some work spent on either an initial theme, and or a combination of the previous + some more advanced components that don't exist in MUI.

I'm on an Alpha branch of MUI, for most of these features. "5.0.0-alpha.17

**Please see animation & the example code in the sandbox**

I have created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/globalthemevariants-material-demo-forked-qxjb3?file=/eleMuiGlobals/variant-extensions.ts), the idea is that the animation effect should be driven from the the palette.

[image]

### Questions

Currently I'm stuck on 3 issues.

1. My IDE doesn't seem to understand the new `Variants`, even though I have added interfaces to make them known. The variants do work at runtime... its just the IDE that doesn't know about them.

[image]

2. How do I get my custom Variant to render the `Palette` class names (I have also added custom palettes), but none of them appear anywhere...

[image]

3. How do you disable the damn ripple , the new way doesn't seem documented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution For 1:

I implemented my interface extension like this.

```
export enum EleMuiVariants {
  EleMuiRounded = "elemuiRounded"
}

export interface EleMuiVariantOverrides {
  [EleMuiVariants.EleMuiRounded]: true;
}

declare module "@material-ui/core/Button/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides extends EleMuiVariantOverrides {}
}
```

Which means that the usage of the variant needs to look like this. (I'll still tinker with TS or the code to support both the enum value & the enum itself.)

```
 <Button variant={EleMuiVariants.EleMuiRounded} color="primary" />
```

### Solution For 2:

> As @Someone Special commented on this answer. The combination of features just don't work together at the moment. I'm going to see if its possible to do a PR with the changes needed to support this to the MUI project.

### Solution For 3:

The `disableRipple` prop has [moved](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1365cd35503be429b03080df90983065d908cd0b/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMuiTheme.test.js#L77) to the component level inside and object called `defaultProps`. (See this test for an example)

Comment: the colors props is not passed if you use custom variant (not at this moment). Best bet is to use custom component.